# Interesting MySQL error creating a Keycloak project on Openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift, keycloak

I try to create a Keycloak app that uses MySQL.
 Hello,

I just want to create a Keycloak app on Openshift which is using MySQL.

1- I have created an Openshift project.

2- I created a MySQL instance (as I am not sure if this template automatically creates one) with these credentials:

user: keycloak

password: password

db : keycloak

3- Then I have copied this: Openshift-template:

https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/master/openshift-examples/keycloak-https.json

But I just changed Keycloak image: "image": "jboss/keycloak:4.8.1.Final"

(as keycloak-openshift image deprecated.)

And I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "tcp:"'.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:338)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "tcp:"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.port(NonRegisteringDriver.java:825)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
    ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem but I think it is most probably a bug as we cannot relate a MySQL app named "mysql" to this Keycloak version and we cannot set DB_ADDR as "mysql". (Which is reported by a user (cjohn001), but not solved)

Just a note for the people who may have the same problem in future:

It is the manipulated Openshift template. I added some extra environment variables and parameters to solve this problem:

https://github.com/helpfularmy/ssoha/blob/master/keycloak-https.json